# Using regex in StandardTokenParsers

Tags: parsing, scala

I'm trying to use regex in my StandardTokenParsers based parser. For that, I've subclassed StdLexical as follows:

```
class CustomLexical extends StdLexical{
  def regex(r: Regex): Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def apply(in:Input) = r.findPrefixMatchOf(in.source.subSequence(in.offset, in.source.length)) match {
      case Some(matched) => Success(in.source.subSequence(in.offset, in.offset + matched.end).toString,
        in.drop(matched.end))
      case None => Failure("string matching regex `" + r + "' expected but " + in.first + " found", in)
    }
  }

  override def token: Parser[Token] =
    (   regex("[a-zA-Z]:\\\\[\\w\\\\?]* | /[\\w/]*".r)     ^^ { StringLit(_) }
      | identChar ~ rep( identChar | digit )               ^^ { case first ~ rest => processIdent(first :: rest mkString "") }
      | ...
```

But I'm a little confused on how I would define a Parser that takes advantage of this. I have a parser defined as:

```
def mTargetFolder: Parser[String] = "TargetFolder" ~> "=" ~> mFilePath
```

which should be used to identify valid file paths. I tried then:

```
def mFilePath: Parser[String] = "[a-zA-Z]:\\\\[\\w\\\\?]* | /[\\w/]*".r
```

But this is obviously not right. I get an error:

```
scala: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.matching.Regex
 required: McfpDSL.this.Parser[String]
    def mFilePath: Parser[String] = "[a-zA-Z]:\\\\[\\w\\\\?]* | /[\\w/]*".r
                                                                          ^
```

What is the proper way of using the extension made on my StdLexical subclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use token based parsing, and reuse StdLexical, I would advise to update the syntax for "TargetFolder" so that the value after the equal sign is a proper string literal. Or in other words, make it so the path should be enclosed with quotes. From that point you don't need to extends StdLexical anymore.

Then comes the problem of converting a regexp to a parser. Scala already has `RegexParsers` for this (which implicitly converts a regexp to a `Parser[String]`), but unfortunately that's not what you want here because it works on streams of `Char` (`type Elem = Char` in `RegexParsers`) while you are working on a sttream of tokens. 
So we will indeed have to define our own conversion from Regex to `Parser[String]` (but at the syntactic level rather than lexical level, or in other words in the token parser).

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.parsing.input._

object MyParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  import lexical.StringLit
  def regexStringLit(r: Regex): Parser[String] = acceptMatch( 
    "string literal matching regex " + r, 
    { case StringLit( s ) if r.unapplySeq(s).isDefined => s }
  )
  lexical.delimiters += "="
  lexical.reserved += "TargetFolder"
  lazy val mTargetFolder: Parser[String] = "TargetFolder" ~> "=" ~> mFilePath
  lazy val mFilePath: Parser[String] = regexStringLit("([a-zA-Z]:\\\\[\\w\\\\?]*)|(/[\\w/]*)".r)  
  def parseTargetFolder( s: String ) = { mTargetFolder( new lexical.Scanner( s ) ) }
}
```

Example:

```
scala> MyParser.parseTargetFolder("""TargetFolder = "c:\Dir1\Dir2" """)
res12: MyParser.ParseResult[String] = [1.31] parsed: c:\Dir1\Dir2

scala> MyParser.parseTargetFolder("""TargetFolder = "/Dir1/Dir2" """)
res13: MyParser.ParseResult[String] = [1.29] parsed: /Dir1/Dir2

scala> MyParser.parseTargetFolder("""TargetFolder = "Hello world" """)
res14: MyParser.ParseResult[String] =
[1.16] failure: identifier matching regex ([a-zA-Z]:\\[\w\\?]*)|(/[\w/]*) expected
TargetFolder = "Hello world"
           ^
```

Note that also fixed your "target folder" regexp here, you had missing parens around the two alternative, plus unneeded spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put in your suggestion, but it seems that StdLexical is kicking in and processing "Z:\..." first, so it processes 'Z' as an identifier -> 'identifier Z', and I get this error: "string literal matching regex ([a-zA-Z]:\\[\w\\?]*)|(/[\w/]*) expected at position 2,26. Token identifier Z found.". It's gone after I override lexical with my own implementation that processes the regex before the identifier case is reached. Not really sure why you don't get that error.

Comment: As I sais I took the liberty to change the syntax a bit: the dir path must be a proper string literal (with quotes). Without this change everything is a lot more complicated. You could make the path token be an Identifier (so no need for quotes) but then you'd need to allow '/', ':' and "\" in identifiers (which is what you apparently tried to do), and then this impacts **every** identifier (thus breaking the parsing). The core problem is that the lexer and parser are separate, the lexer does not know when it parses the char stream if you want a path or an identifier (it has no context).

Comment: Another solution to avoid these problems is to simply not use token based parsing (where there are two separate parts: the lexer and the syntactic parser),  and instead do everything at the same level. By example define `object MyParser extends StdLexical with RegexParsers` and do everything there. Because there is no separation, you know the context everywhere, and as a bonus `RegexParsers` automatically turns every regex into suitable parsers.

Comment: Yes. I ran into the former one - I made the path an identifier and now others are broken. If I choose to use RegexParsers, why would I need to extend from StdLexical? Could you elaborate on what sort of logic would be required there?

Comment: I made the change and switched to RegexParsers, without extending StdLexical. The parser is working and it allowed me to eliminate much of the extra code I had. I still feel like I'm not quite fully understanding how the different Scala combinator elements interact (Parsers, Lexical, Tokens, etc.). Any good resource out there where this is well explained?

Comment: Switching to RegexParsers is certainly for the best. As for why to extend from `StdLexical`, your intuition is good: you should not. I simply pasted (without thinking too much) the declaration from a parser I wrote. It turns out that in my library I was pretty desperate to reduce the (bytecode) size. Extending from `StdLexical` did not give me any additional feature but allowed to reduce the bytecode size. This is because mixing a trait (such as `RegexParsers`) incurs a very significant code size hit, while extending a class (such as `Stdlexical`) does not. Sad but true.

Comment: Concerning good resources, I don't think I can recommend anything else than what google will bring up. I myself always struggle a bit every time I come back to parsers combinatory as documentation is lacking and most introductory texts are pretty elusive on concrete details.

Comment: Great discussion, I have sort of same problem but cannot have both StandardTokenParses and RegexParser alongside each other. would you please help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836294/how-to-define-a-reserve-keyword-in-lexical-object-to-identify-path

Comment: Quoting myself: "Scala already has RegexParsers for this (which implicitly converts a regexp to a Parser[String]), but unfortunately that's not what you want here because it works on streams of Char (type Elem = Char in RegexParsers) while you are working on a sttream of tokens. So we will indeed have to define our own conversion from Regex to Parser[String] (but at the syntactic level rather than lexical level, or in other words in the token parser)." `regexStringLit` in my above snippet is the method you want to create a parser (at the syntactic level) out of a Regex.

Comment: Note though that it will only match the regex as proper string literals (in other words, "quoted").

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles thank you, I tried that but having some errors, if I ask it as a question would you please help me on that?

Comment: Update your original question with a complete and minimal snippet of what you are trying to achieve, along with the error you get, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I have updated my previous question with the error. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/q/30836294/3827280

Answer (score 0):

Just call your function `regex` when you want to get a `Parser[String]` from a `Regex`:

```
def p: Parser[String] = regex("".r)
```

Or make `regex` implicit to let the compiler call it automatically for you:

```
implicit def regex(r: Regex): Parser[String] = ...
// =>
def p: Parser[String] = "".r
```

Comment: `p` is defined in terms of `regex` and `regex` is defined in terms of `p`. Is it ok?

Comment: `regex` is not defined in terms of `p`, why do you think so?