# Parsing a delimited multiline string using scala StandardTokenParser

Tags: scala, parsing

I have found a few similar questions but nothing that seems to directly address my needs here.

I am creating a DSL using Scala and have much of it already defined.  However, part of the language needs to handle blocks of multi-line textual documentation that are collected and handled as individual entities by the parser.  I would like to delimit these blocks in some way (say with something like `{{` and `}}`) and just collect everything between the delimiters and return it as a `DocString` (a `case` class in my parser).  These blocks will then be used to create additional end-user documentation along with the rest of the parsed file(s).

The parser is already structured as a `StandardTokenParsers`-derived class.  I suppose I could convert it to a `RegexParsers`-derived class and just use regular expressions but that would be a major change and a lot of my grammar would have to be reworked.  I am not sure if there would be any advantage to doing this (other than supporting the desired documentation blocks).

I have seen [Using regex in StandardTokenParsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237586/using-regex-in-standardtokenparsers) and found [this](http://scalapatterns.googlecode.com/svn/matcheck/trunk/src/ch/epfl/lara/matcheck/ast/parser/SyntaxParser.scala).  I am not sure either of those will actually handle what I need, however, or how to begin if they do.

If anyone has any ideas as to a viable way to proceed I would appreciate some pointers.

As an example, here is something I have tried (from  [Using regex in StandardTokenParsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237586/using-regex-in-standardtokenparsers)):

```
object DModelParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
    ...
    def modelElement: Parser[ModelElement] =
        (other stuff, not important here) | docBlock

    import scala.util.matching.Regex
    import lexical.StringLit

    def regexBlockMatch(r: Regex): Parser[String] = acceptMatch(
        "string block matching regex " + r,
        {case StringLit(s) if r.unapplySeq(s).isDefined => s})

    val bmr = """\{\{((?s).*)\}\}""".r

    def docBlockStr: Parser[String] = regexBlockMatch(bmr)
    def docBlock: Parser[DocString] = 
      docBlockStr ^^ { s => new DocString(s) }
    ...
}
```

However, when passing it even a single line like the following:

```
{{ A block of docs }}
```

it fails to match causing the parser to stop parsing.  I *think* the problem is in the `case StringLit(s)` in this case but I am not sure.

**Edit**

OK.  `StringLit` *was* a problem.  I forgot that this will only match strings in double quotes.  So I tried replacing the string above with:

```
"{{ A block of docs }}"
```

and it works fine.  However, the multi-line issue still remains.  If I replace this with:

```
"{{ A block 
 of docs }}"
```

Then it still fails to parse.  Again, I think it is the `StringLit` not working across line-feeds.

**Edit**

Another option occurred to me but I am not sure how to make it work in the parser.  If I can read and match a line that only contains the opening delimiter then collect into a `List[String]` all the lines until a line that only contains the closing delimiter that would be sufficient.  Is there a way to do this?

**Edit 6/22/2015**

I went a different direction and this seems to work for the examples I have tried so far:

```
 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771341/scala-regex-multiline-match-with-negative-lookahead
 def docBlockRE = regex("""(?s).*?(?=}})""".r)
 def docBlock: Parser[DocString] =
     "{{" ~> docBlockRE <~ "}}" ^^ { case str => new DocString(str) }
```

Comment: hope your problem has been solved. I have some trouble sort in this area : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30872527/3827280 would you please take a look at it and help me out?

Comment: @Rubbic, see my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote my problem using RegexParser and JavaTokenParser and it is solved but I am curious about this way and I am going to try it because my previous way was more logical!