# Scala regex multiline match with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, scala, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a DSL using Scala's parser combinators.  I have recently changed my base class from StandardTokenParsers to JavaTokenParsers to take advantage of the regex features I think I need for one last piece of the puzzle.  (see [Parsing a delimited multiline string using scala StandardTokenParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747430/parsing-a-delimited-multiline-string-using-scala-standardtokenparser))

What I am trying to do is to extract a block of text delimited by some characters (`{{` and `}}` in this example).  This block of text can span multiple lines.  What I have so far is:

```
  def docBlockRE = regex("""(?s)(?!}}).*""".r)
  def docBlock: Parser[DocString] =
      "{{" ~> docBlockRE <~ "}}" ^^ { case str => new DocString(str) }}
```

where `DocString` is a case class in my DSL.  However, this doesn't work.  It fails if I feed it the following:

```
{{
abc
}}

{{
abc
}}
```

I'm not sure why this fails.  If I put a Deubg wrapper around  have a debug wrapper around the parser (http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-scala-parser-combinators.html) I get the following:

```
docBlock.apply for token 
   at position 10.2 offset 165 returns [19.1] failure: `}}' expected but end of source found
```

If I try a single delimited block with multiple lines:

```
{{
abc
def
}}
```

then it also fails to parse with:

```
docBlock.apply for token 
  at position 10.2 offset 165 returns [16.1] failure: `}}' expected but end of source found
```

If I remove the DOTALL directive `(?s)` then I can parse multiple *single-line* blocks (which doesn't really help me much).

Is there any way of combining multi-line regex with negative lookahead?

One other issue I have with this approach is that, no matter what I do, the closing delimiter **must** be on a separate line from the text.  Otherwise I get the same kind of error message I see above.  It is almost like the negative lookahead isn't really working as I expect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context:

```
scala> val rr = """(?s).*?(?=}})""".r
rr: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?s).*?(?=}})

scala> object X extends JavaTokenParsers {val r: Parser[String] = rr; val b: Parser[String] = "{{" ~>r<~"}}" ^^ { case s => s } }
defined object X

scala> X.parseAll(X.b, """{{ abc
     | def
     | }}""")
res15: X.ParseResult[String] =
[3.3] parsed: abc
def
```

More to show difference in greed:

```
scala> val rr = """(?s)(.*?)(?=}})""".r.unanchored
rr: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (?s)(.*?)(?=}})

scala> def f(s: String) = s match { case rr(x) => x case _ => "(none)" }
f: (s: String)String

scala> f("something }} }}")
res3: String = "something "

scala> val rr = """(?s)(.*)(?=}})""".r.unanchored
rr: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (?s)(.*)(?=}})

scala> def f(s: String) = s match { case rr(x) => x case _ => "(none)" }
f: (s: String)String

scala> f("something }} }}")
res4: String = "something }} "
```

The lookahead just means "make sure this follows me, but don't consume it."

Negative lookahead just means make sure it doesn't follow me.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I forgot about the greediness of the .* which was eating all my text up to *and including* the closing delimiters.  I thought the negative lookahead would take care of that but it didn't.  The non-consuming lookahead is a little confusing.  I guess I have to rethink why negative lookahead *doesn't* work and positive lookahead does.

Answer (score 1):

To match `{{the entire bracket}}`, use this regex:

```
(?s)\{\{.*?\}\}
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/oX0wN1/3).

To match {{`inside the brackets`}}, use this:

```
(?s)(?<=\{\{).*?(?=\}\})
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/oX0wN1/2).

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as much as necessary. Without the `?`, the `.*` will grab the longest match, first matching the whole string then backtracking only as far as needed to allow the next token to match.
- `(?<=\{\{)` is a lookbehind that asserts that what precedes is `{{`
- `(?=\}\})` is a lookahead that asserts that what follows is `}}`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I will take a look at this.  I used to handle regular expressions quite often.  They appear to have changed much over the last 10 years or so and I haven't kept pace. :)  This and som-snytt's answer are both preferable to what I came up with.

Comment: Alright then, if you have questions let me know. :)